# Angular4 ng2-charts TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

I am trying to create a bar chart using data collected from the output of a program. I am using a variable to delay the canvas loading, and i initially thought it was a timing issue so i used an auxiliary function to load it but regardless i get *core.js:4352 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined at ng2-charts.js:520*.

**app.component.ts**

```
public barChartOptions: any = {
  scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
  responsive: true
};
public barChartType: string = 'bar';
public barChartLegend: boolean = false;
public barChartData: number[];
public barChartLabels: number[];

public tempData: number[] = [];
public tempLabels: number[] = [];
public chartReady: boolean = false;

grafico() {
  const url = this.root + 'grafico';
  this.httpclient.get(url).subscribe((res) => {
    for (let key in res) {
      if (res[key].uid == -1) {
        this.barChartLabels = this.tempLabels;
        this.barChartData = this.tempData;
        this.loadchart();
      } 
      else {
        this.tempData.push(res[key].data);
        this.tempLabels.push(res[key].uid);
      }
    };
  });
}

loadchart() {
  this.chartReady = true;
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<canvas
    *ngIf="this.chartReady"
    baseChart
    style="height:230px" 
    [datasets]="this.barChartData" 
    [labels]="this.barChartLabels" 
    [options]="this.barChartOptions" 
    [legend]="this.barChartLegend" 
    [chartType]="this.barChartType" >
</canvas>
```

I asked a more experienced friend but he couldn't help me and although this question was already asked many times here i tried everything i could find in other answers but nothing worked for me, i'd be really glad if someone could help me.

EDIT:
[screenshot of error in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLWKh.png)

Comment: Would be great if you can attach screenshot error at ng2-charts.js: (line 520)

Comment: Done! Could do it only with a link because i dont have reputation

Comment: Try calling "loadchart" method after the loop not inside. And you should handle null condition everywhere for the data you are getting as response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are passing an array of data to the `datasets` field, this does not work you need to pass an array of dataset objects which contain the data array.

basic dataset object:

```js
{
    label: '# of Points',
    data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This solution worked. Had to change array types and now my temporary arrays look like this: 
`this.tempData.push({data: res[key].data, label: ""});
this.tempLabels.push("ID " + res[key].uid.toString()); `